# Angular: Uncheck Checkbox With [(ngModel)]

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, checkbox

I have a form that contains a checkbox
when I add `[(ngModel)]` to the tag, the checkbox will be automatically checked when the page load

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" [(ngModel)]="model.test" value="1"> test
```

I tried to fix this using

```
  ngOnInit() {
   let test = document.getElementById('test') as HTMLInputElement;
   test.checked = false;
  }
```

in the .ts but didn't work

is there any way I can make the checkbox unchecked in the loading of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your model, use:

```
model.text = false;
```

But in normal model must be:

```
let model = [
  {id: 1, label: "Check 1", checked: false},
  {id: 2, label: "Check 2", checked: false},
  {id: 3, label: "Check 3", checked: false}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
this.model.text = false;
```